Daniel 7:4 noun antecedent
Just a grammatical construction question about Dan 7:4:

which was lifted up, made to stand, and given the mind of a man


the eagle, its wings, or both?

I understand that it is natural to assume that it is the beast (Lion) that does these things, but since this is symbolic there is no good reason it isn't the wings, especially since all three actions come immediately after the plucking.
I ask because it is common to interpret this in terms of Nebuchadnezzar and Babylon, but fits human history better in terms of Great Britain and the US. The might of the British Empire did not come into full fruition until after America pulled away. The Prussian axis (German/Russian) fits the Bear (and those are their symbols). Raised up on one side could mean raised up against the first (geographic polarization or two power geopolitics). A polycentric, 4 continent BRICS (emerging from the R) fits the Leopard quite well.
Of course, the final beast interpretation would be even more interesting, since no biological animal could be compared to it.  The implication is that it is not natural in the same sense as the first 3. I believe this refers to a multinational governance run by tech companies, which can be far more ubiquitous and ruthless since it has no grounding in the welfare of a people group but exists for its own ends.
Of course, each of these geopolitical groups existed before they were raised up, so the current tech power could represent a taste of what is to come. Is there any grammatical oddities about the language construction regarding the timing of the last on contrast to the first 3?
Thanks for your help. I recognize it could easily be both/and in terms of the interpretation.  History may not repeat itself but it does rhyme.

Welcome to the Biblical Hermeneutics SE Patricia. We are glad you are here. Please take a moment to take the site tour and check out educating new users and the FAQs. We're passionate about high quality Q&A. Also consider going through the Help Center's sections on asking and answering questions.

I suggest that adjusting a translation to match a speculative interpretation is doing things the wrong way round.

Here is my literal translation of Dan 7:4 -

First - like a lion and wings of an eagle; I watched until its wings
were plucked off and was lifted up from the earth and made to
stand on two feet like a man; a heart of a man was given to it.

Note that the verb וּנְטִ֣ילַת (= "and was made to stand") is singular and thus, its subject must be "lion" as this is the only singular noun before it.
I make no comment about the interpretation of the prophecy.  That is another matter entirely.

Dottard and Jason have explained the translation well. Regarding interpretation, we need to look at the context and note that Daniel has other prophecies of a similar nature which are explicitly tied to known historical events.

Chapter 2, Nebuchadnezzar's dream. We see a statue representing four human kingdoms and then the kingdom of God. The first of these kingdoms is explicitly identified as Nebuchadnezzar/Babylon. This would seem to indicate that the following kingdoms are, successively, the Persian, Greek and Roman.
Chapter 8, the vision of the ram and goat. These animals are identified as Persia and Greece, respectively. Later chapters provide a lot more detail regarding this prophecy.

If we read chapter 7 in context as paralleling the other prophecies, it fits:

The lion is Babylon. The second part of verse 4 probably refers to the humbling of Nebuchadnezzar, recounted in chapter 4.
The bear represents Medo-Persia. "Raised up on one side" parallels the two horns of 8:3, where one is higher than the other, and apparently refers to Persia coming to dominate the alliance.
The leopard is Greece. Its wings likely represent the swiftness of Alexander's conquest (see "touched not the ground" in 8:5), its four heads parallel the four horns of the goat in 8:8 and represent the four kings that succeeded Alexander.
The fourth beast is another question that I'm sure has been asked on this site.

Could Daniel 7 still be talking about something else? We'd need very good reasons to take it out of context and assume it's talking about something very different from the preceding and following prophecies in Daniel. I don't see any such reasons in the text or in the alternate interpretation you've provided. The argument that it "fits human history better in terms of Great Britain and the US" is very subjective - personally, I think it sounds more like trying to force the text to fit a theory.

As a fan of the book of Daniel, I of course had to give this Q., some attention. As it happens, it didn't warrant much attention and I'm surprised at the other two posters for giving in to the OP's "grammatical" inclinations. What you have said here however, while not exactly answering the Q., conforms to the majority of theologians beliefs and is in keeping with my own beliefs. The 4th beast while initially referring to Rome, I believe may well be ongoing and may well involve GB & the US - although I don't hold with the OP's conceptualization -  and therefore is probably best left alone. + 1.

@OldeEnglish the others answered the question that was actually asked, and showed why the OP's reading is impossible. They're good answers but without addressing interpretation they felt incomplete. Regarding the fourth beast, I incline to the view that we're still living in the fourth kingdom. Note that after Alexander's death, his kingdom split into four, but the Greek kingdom didn't end until it was conquered by Rome. Following similar reasoning, the Roman empire split up but the countries that came out of it (including Western Europe, GB, US, perhaps even Russia) are still basically Roman.



Daniel 7:4 ESV - The first was like a lion and had eagles' wings. Then as I looked its wings were plucked off, and it was lifted up from the ground and made to stand on two feet like a man, and the mind of a man was given to it.


When we look at the verse, we see that the actions of being “made to stand,” and “the mind of a man was given” logically refer to the subject of the sentence, which is the “first” beast, described as "like a lion and had eagles' wings.” The antecedent for these actions is the lion-like beast itself, not the wings or the eagle separately.
The plucking action happens to the wings, but the wings are associated with the lion-like beast, as it is the primary subject of the sentence. Therefore, the subject of the actions of being “made to stand,” and “the mind of a man was given” must also be the lion-like beast.
It makes more sense because wings don’t have minds nor can they stand like a man.

Wings do not have minds.
Wings cannot stand like a man.
The subject of these actions must be capable of standing and having a mind.
Therefore, it makes the most sense that the subject of these actions cannot be the wings but must be the lion-like beast itself.


See: the interlinear.
As was also noted: The only singular noun preceding the verb וּנְטִ֣ילַת is “lion” (אַרְיֵה). The wings are plural. The singular form of the verb indicates that its subject should also be singular.

Number agreement involves nouns, adjectives, and verbs corresponding
in terms of singular or plural forms. Number agreement is essential
for maintaining sentence clarity and creating a smooth flow in
language usage. [1]

